# problems opening hdf in R

Tags: r

I have scanned through and can't seem to find any thing that deals with "hdf" in R. I currently use rhdf5 but it works more with the hdf5 file format on R 3.0.2 for windows. any suggestions please?

Comment: Is your input in hdf4 format? You could try converting it to hdf5 and importing that into R, see http://www.hdfgroup.org/h4toh5/

Comment: Its just ".hdf" so I am not so sure but I would assume it is a hdf4 file as it is data from SCIAMACHY. I just checked the link for the h4toh5 and it is a C library. WIs there any "R" library that could do this , please?

Comment: It's not only a C library, but also two command line tools - you should be able to convert your input with http://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/tools/h4toh5/src/unpacked/doc/h4toh5lib_RM.html#Tools-h4toh5 and import that using rhdf5. If that doesn't suit you, please provide more information about your input files - where do you get them from?

Comment: i get them from TEMIS http://www.temis.nl/airpollution/co/co_month_scia.php

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved it by downloading ENVIview and Beat software from ENVISAT directly. It allows for easy changes between data formats. the h4toh5 software too was a good option but would ony run with C library. Thanks, Frank.